# How to combine knockout data-bind: text with hard-coded string?

Tags: html, knockout.js

I want to combine a knockout `data-bind: text` with a hard coded text like the example below:

```html
<h6 data-bind="text: username + 'are now logged in'"></h6>
```

I have tried several different pluses and semicolons etc but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 10):

You need to execute observables to get their value:

```js
ko.applyBindings({ username: ko.observable("johndoe") });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<h6 data-bind="text: username() + 'are now logged in'"></h6>
```

Better is though to use a (pure)Computed observable, which you can unit test:

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.username = ko.observable("johndoe");
  self.loggedInMessage = ko.pureComputed(function(){
    return self.username() + " is now logged in";
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<h6 data-bind="text: loggedInMessage"></h6>
```